# classList and dataset highlighed error in my draw() method why?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

```
    //my TS file:
```

as you see here in my draw() method classList and dataset are highlighed error i dont know why ?

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-game',
      templateUrl: './game.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./game.component.css'],
    })
    export class GameComponent implements OnInit {
      cards = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('.card');
     
      winner = [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9],
        [1, 5, 9],
        [3, 5, 7],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [3, 6, 9],
      ];
      firstPlayer = [];
      secondPlayer = [];
      count = 0;
    
      check(array) {
        let finalResult = false;
        for (let item of this.winner) {
          let res = item.every((val) => array.indexOf(val) !== -1);
          if (res) {
            finalResult = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        return finalResult;
      }
    
      constructor() {
        this.cards.forEach((card) => card.addEventListener('click', this.draw));
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {}
    
      winnerPlayer(p) {
        const modal = document.createElement('div');
        const player = document.createTextNode(p);
        const replay = document.createElement('button');
    
        modal.classList.add('winner');
        modal.appendChild(player);
        replay.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Replay'));
    
        replay.onclick = () => {
          this.rep();
        };
        modal.appendChild(replay);
        document.body.appendChild(modal);
      }
```

the probleme is here vscode show me this message "Property 'classList' and 'dataset' does not exist on type 'GameComponent'.ts(2339)"

```
      draw() {
        if (this.cards == 'card') {
          this.count++;
          if (this.count % 2 !== 0) {
            this.classList.add("x")
            this.firstPlayer.push(Number(this.dataset.index));
            if (this.check(this.firstPlayer)) {
              this.winnerPlayer('Bravo player one you win');
            }
          } else {
            this.classList.add('o');
            this.secondPlayer.push(Number(this.dataset.index));
            if (this.check(this.secondPlayer)) {
              this.winnerPlayer('Bravo player two you win');
            }
          }
          if (this.count === 9) {
            this.winnerPlayer('Draw');
          }
        }
      }
    
      rep() {
        const w = document.querySelector('.winner');
        this.firstPlayer = [];
        this.secondPlayer = [];
        this.count = 0;
        w.remove();
      }
    }
    
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    //My HTML file:
    

    <div class="container">
      <div class="card" data-index="1"></div>
      <div class="card" data-index="2"></div>
      <div class="card" data-index="3"></div>
      <div class="card" data-index="4"></div>
      <div class="card" data-index="5"></div>
      <div class="card" data-index="6"></div>
      <div class="card" data-index="7"></div>
      <div class="card" data-index="8"></div>
      <div class="card" data-index="9"></div>
    </div>
    
    //--------------------------------------
```

the probleme is in classList and dataset in my draw() method; i dont know the solution ??!!!

Comment: From the code, it looks like you are trying to access DOM properties classList and dataset. However, your method is wrong. You are accessing these properties using "this" which is the component instance and has no direct relation to DOM API. You need to query the classList using "document" or Renderer2 (for more angular specific API)

Comment: and how to resolve the probleme ?